# Text is tabular out of alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a series of tabular environments set up, and for some reason one of them is very much out of alignment with the rest.
[image]

The red line on the left shows that the top date is out of alignment with the other dates. Is there a way to fix this?

As a 'bonus question', I am also wondering if there is a way to increase the length of the bar I setup under 'Employment History' to be closer to the dates, in the same way on the left side it is closer to the start of the text. If I should make this a separate question, I will do so.

This is the code I have, reduced as much as possible:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\myrule}{O{1pt} O{3pt} O{black}}{%
    \par\nobreak % don't break a page here
    \kern\the\prevdepth % don't take into account the depth of the preceding line
    %\kern#2 % space before the rule
    {\color{#3}\hrule height #1 width\hsize} % the rule
%   \kern#2 % space after the rule
    \nointerlineskip % no additional space after the rule
}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\definecolor{smokyblack}{rgb}{0.06, 0.05, 0.03}
\definecolor{darkjunglegreen}{rgb}{0.1, 0.14, 0.13}
\definecolor{mygrey}{rgb}{0.0, 0.26, 0.15}
\usepackage[
top    = 0.85cm,
bottom = 1.00cm,
left   = 0.90cm,
right  = 0.70cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\textheight=374pt
\begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\colorbox{white}{\textbf{\LARGE \textcolor{darkjunglegreen}{ZIP ZORN}}}  & \Large{examples@example.com}\\
\colorbox{darkjunglegreen!10}{\textbf{\Large \textcolor{smokyblack}{Adventurer}}} &  \large{555-555-5555 - Narnia, NR}\\
%& \large{New York, NY}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{tabular*}
\break
\textbf{\Large{Employment History}}
\myrule[3pt][10pt][mygrey]  
\vspace{4mm}
\begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \large\textbf{Self-Employed} - \large{Consultant}  & \large{01/0001 - Present}\\
    %   \textit{Analyst} &  %\textit{February 2012 - July 2012}\\
\end{tabular*}
\begin{enumerate}[-]
    \setlength\itemsep{0.6mm}
    \large\item Filler text
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{2mm}
    \begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}

    \large\textbf{Job two}\large{ - Senior Associate}  & \large{08/2015 - 07/2016}\\
    %\textit{Senior Associate} & % \textit{August 2015 - July 2016}\\
\end{tabular*}
\begin{enumerate}[-]
    \setlength\itemsep{0.6mm}
    \large\item Filler text
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{2mm}    
\begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}

    \large\textbf{Job one} - \large{Worker} & \large{95/2056 - 87/9015}\\
%   \textit{Consultant} &  %\textit{May 2013 - June 2015}\\
\end{tabular*}
\begin{enumerate}[-]
    \setlength\itemsep{0.6mm}
    \large\item Filler text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: not really related but `\large{Consultant} ` should be `\large Consultant` size commands do not take an argument.

Comment: The dates are right aligned and therefore not left aligned. If you want them to be left aligned don't use `r` but `l` as a column specifier.

Comment: To make the line end right aligned with the dates change its length from `\hsize` to `7.5in` (the width of your tabular).

Comment: Thanks all! @Skillmon I fixed the line as per your comment, thank you! Changing from r to l for the specifier didn't seem to make any difference though.

Comment: How wide should the textblock be? Is is `7.5in`, which is the argument of `tabularx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see, if the following approach gives result close to what you like to achieve:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top    = 0.85cm,
            bottom = 1.00cm,
            left   = 0.90cm,
            right  = 0.70cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep    = 0.6mm,
                  topsep     = 0pt,
                  leftmargin = *,
                  label      = -,
                  before     = \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},
                  after      = \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
                     }

\begin{document}
\large
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\begin{tabular}{p{5in} l}
\LARGE\textbf{ZIP ZORN}         &   \Large  examples@example.com    \\
\Large \textbf{Adventurer}      &   555-555-5555 - Narnia, NR       \\
    \addlinespace[9pt]
    \midrule[2pt]
    \addlinespace[12pt]
%    \arrayrulecolor{black} % if needed
\textbf{Self-Employed} - Consultant
                                &   01/0001 - Present               \\
\begin{itemize}
    \item Filler text
\end{itemize}                   &                                   \\
\textbf{Job two} - Senior Associate
                                &   08/2015 - 07/2016               \\
\begin{itemize}
    \item Filler text
\end{itemize}                   &                                   \\
    \textbf{Job one} - Worker   &   95/2056 - 87/9015               \\
\begin{itemize}
    \item Filler text
\end{itemize}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

above *mwe* gives:

[image]

as you can see, i omitted all to coloring related stuff (which can be easy to add). Beside this i made the following changes:

- remove package `color` (it is sufficient to have `xcolor`)
- remove page set up out of `gemoetry` setup
- replace `enumerate` package with `enumitem`
- change table format
- merge all tables in one (if complete table is longer than one page, than you need to add `longtable` package in preamble and replace `tabular` with `longtable`
- `enumerate` is replaced by `itemize` and all list are nove insife table cells
- for rules i suggest to use rules from `booktabs` package. they can be colored if this is desired
- font size switch `\large` is moved from table to begin of document (do you really need it?)

i hope that this, mostly off-topic suggestion will help. suggested changes also sole your problem reported in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your revision, I am certainly taking some parts of that!